# How do I create rendered vector field in qgis

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, netcdf

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the "vector field renderer" and "VectFieldCalc" plugins, but I have no idea how to make a vector field of arrows, with directions and magnitude. I have the data loaded currently with two seperate .vrt layers, and have tried many other ways. The data originally came from two netcdf files. It would be really nice if I could make the layer simply from those two rasters.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem as you. I would like to create wind vector from a netcdf file in qgis. I have two fields called "eastward_wind" and "northward_wind" in m/s. Do you have any idea how to extract this vector (using VectFieldCalc or another tool) ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

OK. After who knows how long, I somewhat got it. I had to write a python program to create a .csv file with Latitude, Longitude, u, and v. After I imported my .csv, I was able to use the vector plugins.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, and after some searching found a nice tutorial for how to do this. You don't have to write a program to create a CSV file.

http://marine.copernicus.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/1-QGIS_TO_USE_CMEMS_INFORMATION_level2.pdf

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Can you please flesh out your answer a bit? Link-only answers are frowned upon on this network, as they tend to break and become useless.